# Dual Boot windows with ubuntu, lost ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows

I have a dual boot windows with ubuntu. Recently the linux partition can no longer be found.
I have no clue whatsoever what the cause is. I tried booting with a USB stick, but that also fails.
However I can see the partition in Windows 'Disk Management'.
Does someone have have a tip?

Comment: This will not fix that type of problem, but may show details needed to know issue. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Is this an old BIOS/MBR install. Windows deletes logical Linux partitions from partition table iwth updates. Not seen that issue with UEFI/gpt.

Comment: If you can not boot from the USB you have other problems then a missing partition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried using Boot-Repair, but the USB stick is not recognized, neither are other USB sticks.
The laptop only boots Windows.

Comment: Using DiskGenius I discovered that the /boot/efi directory is empty. Is there a way to (re-)create its content?